# How to setup mocha to run tests in a Gatsby repo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, mocha.js, gatsby

I'm trying to get tests to run in a gatsby repo using Mocha, because we already have a lot of tests using mocha and chai, and we don't want to have 2 different assertion libraries, so we're not using Jest.

The first thing I did, is this:

```
npm i -D mocha chai @testing-library/react
```

Which installs mocha v8 and chai v4, Then I add a naive script in my package.json to see what happens:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha --watch"
}
```

This gives me an error: `unexpected token import` for `import { expect } from 'chai';` in my bare-bones test file. So next step, following Gatsby's conventions:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "npx --node-arg '-r esm' mocha --watch"
}
```

Okay, we're live, but no tests are running, next iteration:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "npx --node-arg '-r esm' mocha --watch 'src/**'"
}
```

Alright, now it crashes because of `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` for a `<div>` in a react component file.

At this point, I wonder if I really have to install babel and all of its machinery just to run a simple test, especially since gatsby does not use babel at all?

Does someone know of a really clean, modern setup that makes writing tests with mocha in Gatsby simple? Can `esm` be taught to read JSX without a pile of hacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> At this point, I wonder if I really have to install babel and all of its machinery just to run a simple test

Unfortunately, yes.

> , especially since gatsby does not use babel at all?

Actually that's not true, it's babel *all* the way down.

---

Thankfully, since Gatsby has already done all the tedious work of setting up babel, it's rather easy to set up your tests.

First, install the missing bits:

```sh
npm i -D @babel/register jsdom jsdom-global
```

Then add a fresh `.babelrc` at the root of the project with the following config:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-gatsby"]
}
```

> You don't need to install `babel-preset-gatsby` since it comes with all Gatsby setup.

That should be it. Now replace `esm` with `@babel/register` & register `jsdom-global`. Also make sure you set your `NODE_ENV` to `test`:

```sh
NODE_ENV=test npx mocha -r @babel/register -r jsdom-global/register ./src/**/*.test.js
```

And that should work.

---

When you add the test command to `package.json`, no needs to use npx:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha -r @babel/register -r jsdom-global/register ./src/**/*.test.js"
}
```

---

If you're testing Gatsby components, here's a few global variables you need to watch out for: `__PATH_PREFIX__`, `__BASE_PATH__`, and `___loader`.

Mock them however you'd like, but for a quick and dirty test:

```
globalThis.__PATH_PREFIX__ = '/'
globalThis.__BASE_PATH__ = './'
globalThis.___loader = { enqueue: () => {} }
```